# How to animate ListPointPlot3D from table?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation

I have a text file which is the following format:

```
1159, 2209, 19, 141
2169, 1827, 23, 54
```

Which I import, sort and gather using:

```
table = Import["/Users/myname/Documents/tablevalues.txt", 
  "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","];
table = Sort[table, #1[[4]] < #2[[4]] &];
a=GatherBy[table, Last];
```

What I would like to do is make a 3D point plot using the first 3 values in every line, an only show the points that have the same 4 value at one time.

So basically, this:

```
ListPointPlot3D[GatherBy[table, Last][[i]][[All, 1 ;; 3]]]
```

where i would be the fourth value in each line, but animated so that I can change the value of i with a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know all the pieces you need except for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).  As a self-contained example:

```
table = RandomInteger[10, {100, 4}];
a = GatherBy[table, Last];

Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[ a[[i]][[All, 1 ;; 3]] ],
 {i, 1, Length @ a, 1}
]
```

---

An additional example this time using [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), and a few customizations.

```
table[[All, 4]] *= 7;  (* change values in fourth column for illustration only *)

a = GroupBy[table, Last -> Most];

Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[a[i], 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"fourth column value is ", i}]],
 {i, Sort @ Keys @ a, ControlType -> Slider}
]
```

---

One more example regarding your need for multiple data sets in one plot.

```
t1 = RandomInteger[10, {100, 4}];
t2 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {100, 4}];

{a, b} = GroupBy[#, Last -> Most] & /@ {t1, t2};

Manipulate[
  ListPointPlot3D[{a[i], b[j]},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 10}, {-5, 10}, {-5, 10}},
    PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"t1 set 4th col val: ", i},
                       {"t2 set 4th col val: ", j}}]
  ],
  {i, Sort @ Keys @ a, ControlType -> Slider},
  {j, Sort @ Keys @ b, ControlType -> Slider}
]
```

Note that I used an explicit [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) to keep the points from visually jumping around.

Comment: Would it be possible to make the slider use values from the 4th column of the text file?

Comment: @yellowdiamond Yes.  For best result which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I am using version 10.4.0.0

Comment: @yellowdiamond Please see my additional example.

Comment: I ran the new code, but the "fourth column .." number is reading in the 10s of thousands rather than highest possible value (from where the data was generated from) of 2500

Comment: I think I got it to work using the first example that you posted.  Thank you!

Comment: @yellowdiamond You did not evaluate `table[[All, 4]] *= 7;` in your actual use case, did you?  That was only included to illustrate that the column four values were being used, rather than simple indexing.

Comment: ...I did.  I'm an idiot haha.  Thank you so much, it works nicely now.

Comment: Also, I'm having a bit of trouble adding a second list of points (so that I have two types of data running at the same time) on the second code posting that you put, however, it seems fine when I try it with the first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @yellowdiamond Do you mean you want two sliders to select from different data sets that are then displayed together?

Comment: yes.  basically pulling the same format of information from two different text files.  Both are indexed through the fourth column, but the data sets might not have points for the exact same value.

Ex: {1,2,3,1} and {1,3,7,2} do not have the same 4th value, so while they are both indexed by the same element number, they can't really be indexed through only one slider.

Comment: @yellowdiamond see update

Comment: The update works perfectly when played in Mathematica, but it does not export well when you use AutorunSequencing->All as an option in Manipulate.  I get the "Iterator (...) does not have appropriate bounds" error.  Online articles say that changing the iteration step size for the slider helps, but that would omit a large amount of data so it would not be optimal